# How to resume click event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have used `unbind` to detach the
the click event for certain condition. After that I want to resume that click event. How to do this?

```
jQuery('#div1 span').click(function(){
    if(jQuery('#div1 a:last').hasClass('current'))
    {
    jQuery('#div1 span').unbind(click);
    }

}
    jQuery('#div1 a').click(function(){

         jQuery(this).addClass('current');
//here i want to resume click event for #div1 span is this possible
    });

<div id ="div1"><span></span><a></a><a></a><a></a></div>
```

Here when the current class is not with last anchor I want to trigger click on span.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly `.bind()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)</sup> and `.unbind()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)</sup> a method:

```
function my_click_handler(event) {
    // click handler code
}

// bind that handler to #element
$('#element').bind('click', my_click_handler);

// remove the handler
$('#element').unbind('click', my_click_handler);

// bind again
$('#element').bind('click', my_click_handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier if you just checked for a variable like `clickHandlerEnabled` in your onclick event handler instead of unbinding and re-binding the event handler.

If it's element-specific you could store it in its `data()``:

```
$('.elem').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).data('clickDisabled')) {
        return;
    }
});
```

And to set it:

```
$('#someElem').data('clickDisabled', true /* or false to re-enable clicks */);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you call Jquery click event again under other condition to resume it, jquery will automatically bind it again.